# Getting unique file names by specific paths only

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command where I get the count of all file names that begin with 2010

```
find folder_name/ -path '*/*/*/*/2010*'
```

This works fine and I get valid results. However, say for instance I have this file structure:

```
*/atl/apple/banana/20101004
*/atl/apple/oranges/20101004
```

These would be the same category since both fall under atl. So instead of the count being 2, it should be 1. Is there a way I can make it so that I only get unique values for each city name (atl)?

Note: The date at the end is a file name. There is no file extension.

**EDIT**
Let's say I have this command

```
find example/ -path '*/*/*/*/2010*'
```

and I get these as results:

```
example/atl/apples/bananas/20100510 //1 instance of this date in atl
example/atl/apples/oranges/20100510 //This date is a duplicate and should not be counted
example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100510 //1 instance of this date in nyc
example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100511 //1 instance of this date in nyc
example/bkg/apples/bananas/20100510 //1 instance of this date in bkg
```

In this example, the count should be 4. The 20100510 in atl is shown more than once, so it should only be counted once.

Comment: 'So instead of the count being 2, it should be 2.'...? Do you mean that instead of being 2 it should be 1?

Comment: `So instead of the count being 2, it should be 2.` ? It is 2. And no, you don't get all names that begin with 2010, that's `-name '2010*`. You get all the paths that begin with 2010 in 4 directory.

Comment: @Graeme Yes sorry

Comment: Is `find folder_name/ -path '*/*' -maxdepth 2` not ok? Aa, no, because there may be folders witch don't contain files that start with 2010, right?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, there are some files that don't start with 2010.

Comment: So you want to count the number of distinct top-level directories which have at least one match for the rest of the glob?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, that sounds about right. So for example we could have `*/atl/apples/bananas/20101004, */atl/apples/oranges/20101004, */atl/apples/bananas/20101003` the count here should be 2.

Comment: So the pair 'second-level directory' and 'filename' should be unique? Is `a/atl/apples/bananas/20101004` and `b/atl/apples/bananas/20101004`  equal 2?

Comment: I'm... actually less sure that I correctly understood your question than I was before. [Edit]ing the question to add sample data and outputs that rule out misinterpretations would be helpful. (Much as how a test suite that only tests the behavior you *want* and doesn't attempt to test behavior in presence of unexpected data is often useless, an example that only shows one case isn't very helpful at narrowing how that case should be understood).

Comment: Being clear in the question isn't just for your benefit as someone who wants an answer -- it's also to benefit other people who are trying to judge answers' applicability; if I don't know what your question is, I can't be certain any answer addressed it correctly and deserves an upvote.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry about that, I have edited the question with more details

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When you say last piece and ignoring all prior elements, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean for the sample data you provided, the stated desired output can be taken looking *only* at the top-level directories (`atl`, `nyc`, `bkg`) and the filenames (`201000510`, `201000511`), ignoring all other path elements. I don't know if that's intended behavior or if it's accident of your sample data selection; I'm *assuming* it's intended behavior in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort` to show unique city/date pairs, plus `wc` to count them, and `bash` *process substitution* to make it look better:

```
find folder_name/ -path '*/*/*/*/2010*' | 
sort -t '/' -k 2,2 -k 5,5 -u | tee >(echo "Count: $(wc -l)")
```

Output, (given the *"results"* sample data):

```
example/atl/apples/bananas/20100510
example/bkg/apples/bananas/20100510
example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100510
example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100511
Count: 4
```

Or to print just the city/date pairs, add a `cut` before the `tee`:

```
find folder_name/ -path '*/*/*/*/2010*' | 
sort -t '/' -k 2,2 -k 5,5 -u | cut -d '/' -f 2,5 | tee >(echo "Count: $(wc -l)")
```

Output:

```
atl/20100510
bkg/20100510
nyc/20100510
nyc/20100511
Count: 4
```

---

How it works:

1. `find` some files, five levels deep.
2. Tell `sort` to sort by the 2nd and 5th fields, printing only the unique city/date lines.  Note that *two* `-k` switches are needed; just using `-k 2,5` won't work the same way.
3. Count the lines with `wc`.

Comment: This looks correct, however, how can I get the path and not just the file names? for example `*/atl/apples/bananas/20101004`?

Comment: @user2896120, See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `awk` to select just the  fields that are the city name and the file name, you can pipe to `sort -u`, then `wc` to count. This will produce a single count for all results from the same city. Something like:

```
find folder_name/ -path '*/*/*/*/2010*' |
    awk -F/ '{ print $2, $5 }' |
    sort |
    uniq -c
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the directory path and not just the count? Like the city, plus the fruit names?

Comment: @user2896120 You mean you want a count for each city/date?

Comment: I mean yours gives the unique count for each date in each city. However, I want the path to that date. For example, `example/atl/oranges/bananas/20100503`

Comment: @user2896120, it is easy to do an individual count for each city/date. I have updated to do that. Keeping track of all the original paths is harder though. CharlesDuffy's answer is more on track with that.

Answer (score 0):

Doing everything but the `find` itself in native bash (rather than relying on external tools) might look like the below.

---

Given the setup described in your question:

```
mkdir -p example/{atl,nyc,bkg}/apples/{bananas,oranges}
touch \
  example/atl/apples/bananas/20100510 \
  example/atl/apples/oranges/20100510 \
  example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100510 \
  example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100511 \
  example/bkg/apples/bananas/20100510
```

...the implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A seen=( )

while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do
  name=${name#example/}  # ignore the leading example/
  first_piece=${name%%/*}
  last_piece=${name##*/}
  seen[${first_piece}/${last_piece}]=1
done < <(find example -type f -print0)

echo "Number of distinct first/last pairs: ${#seen[@]}"
echo "Those individual pairs are:"
printf ' - %s\n' "${!seen[@]}"
```

...properly emits as output:

```
Number of distinct first/last pairs: 4
Those individual pairs are:
 - atl/20100510
 - bkg/20100510
 - nyc/20100510
 - nyc/20100511
```

Answer (score 0):

By inspiring me from @charles, i created the following structure :

```
mkdir -p example/{atl,nyc,bkg}/apples/{bananas,oranges}
touch \
example/atl/apples/bananas/20100510 \
example/atl/apples/oranges/20100510 \
example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100510 \
example/nyc/apples/bananas/20100511 \
example/bkg/apples/bananas/20100510 \
example/bkg/coconuts/bananas/20100510
```

Then, assuming you are consider that a file is a duplicate since it is in the same **level-2** subdirectory (apples or coconuts), i suggest the following command :

```
for i in $(find example -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d); do find $i -path '*/*/*/*/2010*'|awk -F\/ '{print $NF}'|sort -u;done|wc -l
```

The result is :

```
5
```

If you want to consider that a file is a duplicate since it is in the same **level-1** subdirectory (atl, nyc or bkg), then use this :

```
for i in $(find example -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d); do find $i -path '*/*/*/*/2010*'|awk -F\/ '{print $NF}'|sort -u;done|wc -l
```

The result is :

```
4
```